# Is it a bad practice to have too many nested PHP if-statements?

Tags: php, if-statement

Right now, I have something like this:

```
<?php if ( ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
    <?php if ( $count >= 1 ) : ?>
        <?php if ( $count == 1 ) : ?>
            <h2 class="dark-title"><?php _e( 'Top Reply (Latest)' ); ?></h2>
        <?php else : ?>
            <h2 class="dark-title"><?php _e( 'Top Replies (Latest)' ); ?></h2>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

There are 3 nested if-statements I would like to know if this is a bad practice. If it is, how can I clean this code?

Comment: too many `<>php ... ?>` seems a bit hard to read to me

Comment: Isn't the if(count >= 1) statement redundant here?

Comment: @vascowhite No, because it excludes `$count == 0` (and presumable negative, too)

Comment: @vascowhite Yeah I need to include the 0.

Comment: @phihag @alexchenco but $count==1 excludes 0 and negative.

Comment: @vascowhite in short: `0: ""`, `1: Reply`, `2+: Replies`

Comment: @phihag ahh, gotchya! Didn't see that. Thanks. +1 for the lesson :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is if the conditions are very simple and their are no else cases.

Also, opening useless `<?php` processing instructions and using the uncommon `endif` form instead of braces are definitely not encouraged. Instead, write:

```
<?php
if (!is_front_page() && ($count >= 1)) {
    echo '<h2 class="dark-title">';
    echo _e(($count==1) ? 'Top Reply (Latest)' : 'Top Replies (Latest)');
    echo '</h2>';
}
?>
```

Comment: When you are creating a template, it is quite common to use `<?php` and the other version of control structures (`if`-`endif`).

Comment: The readability of the code is the *main* reason I use a templating system.

Answer (score 1):

> ...if you need
>   more than 3 levels of indentation, you're screwed...
>    - [Linus Torvalds](http://www.chris-lott.org/resources/cstyle/LinuxKernelCodingStyle.txt)

It's fine what you've done. In general your firstmost care should be whether your code is readable, not how many levels of nesting you use.

Comment: Only if you still use `80-character terminal screen`.

Comment: that's **entirely** not the point! The quote - no matter the context it's in - says just that - any code that has 4 levels of indentation or more - has smell.

Comment: Your link smells too. :) No offence... certainly the age of your answer. Maybe you can take this: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/alfs/view/hacker/part2/hacker/coding-style.html

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly a **bad idea to repeat markup**. If you want to change something, add a class for example, you have to do it in two places.

In some cases, when you just want to assign a value based on a condition, you can use the **ternary operator** (`condition ? iftrue : iffalse`), just never nest it.

```
<?php if ( ! is_front_page() && $count >= 1  ) : ?>
    <h2 class="dark-title">
         <?php _e( $count == 1 ? 'Top Reply (Latest)' : 'Top Replies (Latest)' ); ?>
    </h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly common. If you want to clean up the code, refactor stuff into separate functions/methods. In your specific case you could also get rid of one nesting by doing if($count == 1) and then elseif($count > 1).